# why polymorphism doesn't matters when a method is overloaded?

Tags: java, oop, overloading, overriding

i know that overloaded methods are determined at compile time based on the reference type which invokes the method while overrided methods is determined by the actual object type of the reference invoking he method, the question is why polymorphism only matters about overriding and not overloading?

Comment: What do you mean by "only matters"? It would help if you'd give a concrete example, saying what *does* happen and what you'd *expect* to happen.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Overloading is another polymorphism, this time of functions rather than objects. What exactly do you mean by 'doesn't matter'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation mechanism that makes polymorphism in Java possible is the dynamic dispatch of a method based on the runtime type of its first argument (in a call `a.method(b, c)`, `a` can be considered the first argument of the method). Java is therefore a *single dispatch* OOP language. The upshot is that all other arguments don't participate in this mechanism and their type is determined statically at compile time. So for example if you have

```
class MyObject {
  public boolean equals(MyObject o) { ... }
}
```

and then

```
MyObject m1 = new MyObject();
Object o = new MyObject();
System.out.println(m1.equals(o));
```

can never print `true` since your method is not being called. The compiler saw a call `MyObject.equals(Object)` and compiled it as a call of the inherited method `Object.equals(Object)`. The runtime method dispatch mechanism will only decide which overriding method `equals(Object)` to call.

Comment: @Eslam I can try, but you'll need to cooperate: what exactly in my answer do you understand, and what exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

polymorphism , as the name implies , is when a method "of the same form" manifests different behaviours under different contexts. The term "same form" means "same signature". That implies you cannot relate polymorphism with overloaded methods because they have "different forms" to begin with. Another way to think about it is - you need a type and a subtype to see polymorphism in action - overloaded methods again are defined in the context of a single class.

Answer (score 0):

This is for technical reasons. Usually only the `this` pointer, as hidden first parameter of the method, is analyzed at runtime to determine the method to be called.

When other parameters, too, are analyzed it is called [Multiple Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). There are a few languages that support multiple dispatch natively.

Answer (score -1):

You are confused on this.
`Overloading` refers to selecting one of the methods having the same name but different signature in the *same* class (not hierarchy).
`Overriding` is chose among methods of the same name depending on the runtime type among those inherited by parent classes.
If you have a base class and a derived class with a method of the same name and signature then this is `overriding` and at runtime the correct is determined.

For `overloading` the compiler picks the correct version of method to use, among the available in the *same class*.
No need to find a runtime type. Compiler can figure this out at compile time

Comment: Not mine, but I'd guess it's because OP stated in the question that he already understands the concepts, but wonders WHY there's such a difference.

Comment: You are not helping matters with this explanation. It's factually incorrect to begin with and apart from that simplifies matters to the point of incorrectness. See http://www.stratos.me/2008/07/java-crash-course-5-overloading-vs-overriding/

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik:But I think I address this.My point is that there is no need to find a runtime type for overloading methods since overloading is not relevant to inheritance.

Comment: A signature is not permitted twice or more in the same class (read the link and see the definition of signature). It will result in a compile-time error. For an override, the name is immaterial; the _signature_ is what matters. If a method in class B has the same name as one in class A, but a different signature, this is not an override and the method can be bound at compile-time.

Comment: `A signature is not permitted twice or more in the same class`. Oh, ok I corrected these ill statements.